# crontab sudo docker permission denied

Tags: docker, cron

I have a bash script that works fine and I'm trying to run it using crontabs.

The main issue is that when I run the script it asks me for my sudo password in order to execute the docker command. Therefore, when I'm trying to execute the script using crontabs I get the following errors:

**Permission denied**

or

**Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon**

This is my bash script:

```
PG_USERNAME=username
PG_DB=example-db
echo "Removing 7 days inactive users..."
sudo docker exec -it example-app psql -U $PG_USERNAME $PG_DB \
-c "DELETE from users where created_at <= current_date at time zone 'UTC' - interval '7 days' and is_activated = false;" \
&& echo "Users removed!" \
|| echo "failed to run command"
```

and this is what I'm running inside crontab -e:

```
* * * * * /home/user/Desktop/Projects/example/remove-inactive-users.sh >> /home/user/Desktop/Projects/example/log.log 2>&1
```

I have tried changing file permissions without success:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/user/Desktop/Projects/example/remove-inactive-users.sh
sudo chmod u+x /home/user/Desktop/Projects/example/remove-inactive-users.sh
```

Comment: Can you directly interact with the database using `psql`, rather than using debugging tools to get direct access to the container?  Or, can you write some sort of administrative endpoint in your application to do this cleanup?  Or, since `docker` commands legitimately require root permission, can you have the root user run this cron job (without `sudo`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I changed the bash script file permissions:

```
sudo chmod 715 remove-inactive-users.sh
```

then I got the error: **the input device is not a TTY**

and I solved it changing the docker exec line from the script into this:

```
docker exec example-app psql...
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your are runing under user `$USER`

You should ensure `/etc/sudoers` allows your script to be run by the cron user without password (NOPASSWORD option), something like :

`$USER ALL=NOPASSWD:/home/user/Desktop/Projects/example/remove-inactive-users.sh`

alternatively, you could also give the right to that username to call docker directly (not with sudo)  :
`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && exec sg docker newgrp $(id -gn) && sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: non of these worked.

Comment: Maybe they did because you were then able to remove the "sudo" before "docker exec" in the script after their execution !

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from @Julien is correct at the `sudo` realm.

A more fundamental approach is to create a dedicated technical user for running the cron job.

The approach of dedicated user provide additional benefits for logging and process capabilities isolation.

See Docker official documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) , and this helpful [article](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/add-user-to-docker-group-ubuntu/).

Use a technical user with no shell and additional groups docker and wheel.

```
sudo useradd -M -G docker,wheel docker_user_5
```

After testing `docker_user_5` to run docker from cli.

Add crontab task to `docker_user_5`